# How to change Unity png import setting via script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a huge png file folder (1000+ png files), and I want to use them as 2D and UI Sprite. But when I import these, it's imported as Default. I can change each of these manually, but since there are a number of files, it would be q really tedious and time-consuming task. Is there a way to change these file's import setting via script, or just import as 2D and UI sprite setting, not Default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try selecting all of them using Ctrl+A in the project folder view of the PNGs. You can then change an inspector value for all at once.

Make sure only PNGs are selected, or else, the inspector won't show the respective toggler interface.

If the PNGs are in multiple sub-folders, you can still select all of them. Just search, in the project explorer pane search box, for `t:Texture2D`

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but actually these files are not in one folder, but it has its own hierarchy. So doing so would not be much better than doing each manually.

Comment: I tried `importer.textureType = TextureImporterType.Sprite;` with UnityEditor, but it seems it just changes texture setting, not creating usable sprite.

Comment: You can still select all of them even if they are in different folders. Just search, in the project explorer pane search box, for t:Texture . Then Ctrl+A the search result. I'll add this to my answer.

Comment: Careful though because `t:Texture` also returns e.g. all `RenderTexture`s. Rather use `t:Texture2D` ;)

Answer (score 1):

unity3d inspector show all mutual features of objects you select. select them all and change all of them to Sprite 2D